# Using foreach to insert many things into TABLE

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

I am unsure of how to properly insert many rows into my table. It's been a few years since I did any DB stuff. Is it alright to just do something like this?:

```
foreach(var something in somelist)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con, str);

    // Insert row into db
}
```

Comment: google it. you will find it.

Comment: I would suggest putting the connection outside the loop because then you would either have to open it, insert, then close in each loop.

Answer (score 5):

Sample code:

```
using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection (conString))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach(var something in somelist)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (insertSQLString, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", something.SomeVal1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", something.SomeVal2);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean with "many rows" and where these rows originate from, you might use bcp utility or SqlBulkCopy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Both will work much faster than RBAR approach.